# What is the shortest way of getting this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

What is the shortest/right/nice way to get this? Where `f` is the form alias for `Customer` model with `customer_contract_id` and belong_to `CustomerContact` model.

```
<%= f.object.customer_contact.blank? ? '':f.object.customer_contact.name %>
```

this is not working

```
<%= f.object.customer_contact.name ||= '' %>
```

I apologize upfront for any confusion/frustration. I appreciate any help that I can get!

Comment: The best solution would be to use the Null Object Pattern:
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object

Answer (score 2):

Can you try it like this?

```
<%= f.object.customer_contact.present? ? f.object.customer_contact.name : ''  %>
```

Please note the space between `:` and the two outputs. And `.present?` is the reverse of `.blank?`

---

For future references, I think this table would be of some help to you.

[image]

*Credits for this table should go to* [Sibevin Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232710/sibevin-wang)

Hope this helps?